# Cannot resolve symbol read in org.apache.spark.read

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is the problem with following code in scala spark?

```
import org.apache.spark
// ...
val path in = "D:\\myfolder\\myfile.csv"
spark.read(pathIn).csv()
```

> error: cannot resolve symbol "read"

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.12.1</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I have added some dependencies cuz can't import SparkSession.

Comment: Did you at least read the [basic documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/)? You need to instantiate a **SparkSession** and then you can call `read` on that instance. Usually, that instance is called `spark`,but that it is different from the package `spark` you used.

Answer (score 2):

Please use following. You need spark-core and spark-sql as dependencies.

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val spark : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("test")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val pathIn = "D:\\myfolder\\myfile.csv"
    spark.read.csv(pathIn).show()
```

Comment: what I need to use `SparkSession`? When I write this `val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Intro")
      .getOrCreate` then `Cannot resolve symbol SparkSession`

Comment: I have updated the answer with import. Try the whole thing. If it works then plz accept the answer.

Comment: ye the same problem: `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` gives: `Cannot resolve symbol SparkSession`

Comment: @wykopowiedz have you added spark to you dependencies, post your build file

Comment: are you using old spark? which version?

Comment: You also need to add 'spark-sql_2.12'. SparkSession is part of that. compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.4'

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean scala.util.Properties$.coloredOutputEnabled()'` this is whole my project: https://github.com/woblak/training/blob/master/spark/spark-dataframe-start/src/main/scala/com/woblak/scalastarter/Main.scala

Comment: I can't correlated this error to the code you provided. what is full stack trace? should this be a separate question?